# I want to Display fields from my site properties

Tags: typo3, typoscript

(mask extension - backendlayout) - but only the image will be display.
The same code already works with a menu. But without the menu it will not display my TITLE from site property. The field name is correct!

```
lib.blog_header = COA
lib.blog_header {

  20 = COA
  20{
    wrap = <div class="blog_header inner"><div class="row">|</div></div>

    5 = TEXT
    5.wrap = <span class="titel">|</span>
    5.value.field = tx_mask_blog_titel

    10 = FILES
    10 {

      references {
        table = pages
          uid.data = field:uid
            fieldName = tx_mask_blog_image
      }

      begin = 0
      maxItems = 1

      renderObj = IMAGE
      renderObj {
        wrap = <div class="teaser-img col-md-6">|</div>
        altText.data = file:current:alternative
        titleText.data = file:current:title
        params = class="image-embed-item lazy"
        file.width = 500c
        file.height = 400c
        layoutKey = picturetag
        file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
        file.crop.data = file:current:crop
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understand your problem...

You can use fields of the pages table of the current page via [getText](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/DataTypes/Index.html?highlight=gettext#gettext):

```
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.data = TSFE : page|nav_title
```

And you can use properties of your site/siteconfiguration via [getText](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UseSiteInTypoScript.html#using-site-configuration-in-typoscript)

```
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.data = site:base
page.10.wrap = This is your base URL: |
```